# Caminho é arquivo ou diretório (pasta)

Tags: delphi

Como faço para checar se um caminho aponta para um arquivo ou pasta? Não tenho a mínima de ideia de como fazer.

Um caminho de pasta ou diretório seria:

```
C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\bin
```

Um de arquivo:

```
C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\bin\bds.exe
```

Comment: Vc pode fazer uma verificação pra ver o que ele é, uma sugestão seria Para diretório, tente o comando 
if DirectoryExists('c:\path') then ...
E para arquivo use:
if FileExists(fileName)
  then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma forma segura de verificar se é diretório é a seguinte:

```
function IsDirectory(const Path: String): Boolean;
var
  F: TSearchRec;
  NormPath: String;
begin
  NormPath:= ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Path);
  if FindFirst(NormPath, faDirectory, F) = 0 then
  begin
    Result:= (F.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0;
    FindClose(F);
  end
  else
  begin
    Result:= False;
    //Mensagem adicional que caminho não existe, se desejar
  end;
end;
```

Prefiro dessa forma, pois terei como identificar se existe o caminho e além disso poder dizer se é arquivo ou pasta.

Comment: Realmente, desta forma a função fica bem mais robusta, além de poder retornar ao usuário a informação se ele selecionou ou não um arquivo por exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a dica do @Bacco e @bfavaretto e aproveitando para passar um caminho para documentação, o correto seria a função:

```
function isFolder(dir:string):boolean;
begin
  Result := DirectoryExists(dir);
end;
```

Um bom repositório para conhecer os tipos e funções da RTL (Run Time Library) do delphi é o DeplhiBasics, como por exemplo este link sobre a função [Directory Exists](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=DirectoryExists)

Comment: Boa resposta, há um pequeno problema, no entanto e é por isso que prefiro a abordagem que sempre uso, que é utilizar o TSearchRec. Pois, quando não existe o arquivo, a função isFolder que você fez retorna false, sem a possibilidade de identificar se realmente não é pasta, ou se o caminho não existe

Answer (score 0):

Com a dica de @Raul, fiz essa função:

```
function isFolder(dir:string):boolean;
var
fof : boolean;
begin
if FileExists(dir) then
fof := false
else
fof := true;
Result := fof;
end;
```

Se retornar true, é uma pasta, se false, um arquivo.

Comment: Eu não sei nada de delphi, mas parece que essa função vai retornar um falso positivo se você passar o caminho de um arquivo inexistente, não?

Comment: Seria legal aprender a trabalhar com boolean. Em praticamente nenhuma linguagem faz sentido usar `if` e muito menos `else` pra retornar valor lógico. O que você fez com um monte de linhas é a mesma coisa que escrever apenas `Not  FileExists() ` Além do mais, como já disse o Raul, vc deve usar `DirectoryExists()`. Como o bfavaretto disse, se o arquivo não existir, sua função vai achar que é um diretório.

Comment: Sugiro a remoção dessa resposta, já que está errada.

Answer (score 0):

Melhorando um pouco essa função:

```
function isFolder(dir:string):boolean;
begin
  Result := not FileExists(dir);
end;
```